# How do I read a json file in a Github Action using a windows hosted runner

Tags: github-actions

I have the following snippet of code to read a json file in a linux hosted runner. How do I do the same using windows?

```yaml
    - id: getParams
      run: |
        content=`cat ./server.main.params.json`
        # the following lines are only required for multi line json
        content="${content//'%'/'%25'}"
        content="${content//$'\n'/'%0A'}"
        content="${content//$'\r'/'%0D'}"
        # end of optional handling for multi line json
        echo "::set-output name=packageJson::$content"
    
    #testing output from the previous command
    - name: echo ServerName
      run: echo "${{fromJson(steps.getParams.outputs.packageJson).parameters.ServerName.value}}.suffix"
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried and how it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do the same thing on a windows runner by informing `shell: bash` for each step, to use `bash` instead of the default shell for windows (which is `powershell`).

```yaml
 - id: getParams
   shell: bash
   run: |
      content=`cat ./server.main.params.json`
      # the following lines are only required for multi line json
      content="${content//'%'/'%25'}"
      content="${content//$'\n'/'%0A'}"
      content="${content//$'\r'/'%0D'}"
      # end of optional handling for multi line json
      echo "::set-output name=packageJson::$content"
    
    #testing output from the previous command
    - name: echo ServerName
      shell: bash
      run: echo "${{fromJson(steps.getParams.outputs.packageJson).parameters.ServerName.value}}.suffix"
```